# Restore Postgres Server from Backup Plain File with PG_Admin or somethin else?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I have created a Backup for the Postgres server via PG Admin 6.17. I would now like to import this plain sql file again on a new server, but there is no button for Restore Server Backup similar to the one for the Backup.
[image]

How can I restore the file (60GB) on a new Server Postgres 15? Reimport via Query-Tool did not work. Also i could not find a psql query for reimporting server. (only DB)

Comment: You didn't look to hard: 1) [Backup/Restore](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.2/backup_and_restore.html) 2) From [Restore](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.2/restore_dialog.html): *You can use the Query Tool to play back the script created during a plain-text backup made with the Backup dialog*. Though for that size file I would just use `psql`.

Comment: Of course i looked up the doku but the query tool does absolutly nothing, if i try to load the file. Also the Restore dialog restores my DBs but not the plain SQL Server File. So there is no way to use the gui?

Comment: 1) In your question you did not say you looked up Backup/Restore and tried the Query Tool. Explicit is better then implicit when creating a problem report. 2) If you want to use the GUI then dump using the custom file format instead of plain text. You will also get the benefit of compression leading to a smaller file size. 3) If you are stuck with the plain text version then you will need to use `psql`.

Comment: That's the problem, you can export a server - and I'm only talking about servers, not DBs - as plain. Unfortunately I could not find a command for psql that restores the server, the documentation always writes about DBs. But I will keep looking.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that you where backing up the entire server. In that case [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) was used. I would read the section under *The following command-line options control the database connection parameters.*.  A minimum command would be `psql -p <some_port> -f <dump.file>`